# Javascript: dynamic calculation input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery calculator:

```
   <p class="price" data-base-price="50">$<span>80</span></p>

    <select name="s1" class="price-option">
        <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="s2" class="price-option">
        <option value="1" data-price="30">Item 3</option>
        <option value="2" data-price="40">Item 4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="price-option-input" id="price-option-input">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.price-option').change(function(){
    var price = parseInt($('.price').data('base-price'));

    $('.price-option').each(function(i, el) {
      price += parseInt($('option:selected', el).data('price'));
    });
    price += parseInt($('#price-option-input').val());

    $('.price span').text(price);
  }); 
});
```

This calculator is working, but the problem is when I enter value for text input the result in `price` is not updating dynamically (I need to choose another option in selector for result updating)

Comment: try implementing onBlur on your text input

Comment: or try to use the onKeyUp event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add keyUp event

```
 calculate = function(){
    var price = parseInt($('.price').data('base-price'));

    $('.price-option').each(function(i, el) {
      price += parseInt($('option:selected', el).data('price'));
    });
    price += parseInt($('#price-option-input').val());

    $('.price span').text(price);
}


$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#price-option-input', .price-option').change(calculate);
  $('#price-option-input', .price-option').keyup(calculate);
});
```

I think it´s worth it to explain that change event is fired when you unselect the input, or, in number type, when you use the up/down buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to do the computation, triggering the change event.

Example:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
   $('.price-option').trigger("change");
});
```

Or, you can listen the keyup event from the input and at the enter key press, do the computation. The question is: when do you want to do the computation? With the answer, listen to the proper event and do the computation.

Comment: So... when do you want to do the computation? This was an example of how you can trigger the change's event from $('.price-option'). You can trigger it when the input lost focus - blur() - or at the keyup/keypress, checking if the return/enter key has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to use `.html` because that will set the inner HTML:

```
$('.price span').html(price);
```

And for future reference, multi-selectors like that aren't near as efficient as something like this:

```
$('.price').find('span').html(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code and it works fine now http://plnkr.co/edit/pWSEimrKkA200jQK9w5a?p=preview

HTML:

```
 <p class="price" data-base-price="50">$<span>80</span></p>

<select name="s1" class="price-option">
    <option value="1" data-price="10">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="20">Item 2</option>
</select>

<select name="s2" class="price-option">
    <option value="1" data-price="30">Item 3</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="40">Item 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="price-option-input" id="price-option-input" onchange='updatePrice()'>
```

JS:

```
function updatePrice(){

    var price = parseInt($('.price').data('base-price'));
console.log(price);
    $('.price-option').each(function(i, el) {
      price += parseInt($('option:selected', el).data('price'));
    });
    price += parseInt($('#price-option-input').val());

    $('.price span').text(price);

}
```